# swapping checkboxes in PHP using javascript

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, checkbox

trying to flip-flop values of two checkbox arrays in PHP using javascript from a hyperlink.  the issue i am facing is that php wants the checkbox array to use [ ] and javascript does not.

Here is my code...what code would you suggest to make the checked items in checkbox2 = checkbox1 AND checkbox1 = checkbox2?

```
<a id='swap' href=\"javascript: swapContacts();\">Swap</a>
<br>
<input class='c_contactmethods' type='checkbox' name='checkbox1[]' value='1'>Phone<br>
<input class='c_contactmethods' type='checkbox' name='checkbox1[]' value='2'>Email<br>
<input class='c_contactmethods' type='checkbox' name='checkbox1[]' value='3'>Text<br>
<input class='c_contactmethods' type='checkbox' name='checkbox1[]' value='4'>Mail<br>
<br>
<input class='c_co_contactmethods' type='checkbox' name='checkbox2[]' value='1'>Phone<br>
<input class='c_co_contactmethods' type='checkbox' name='checkbox2[]' value='2'>Email<br>
<input class='c_co_contactmethods' type='checkbox' name='checkbox2[]' value='3'>Text<br>
<input class='c_co_contactmethods' type='checkbox' name='checkbox2[]' value='4'>Mail<br>
```

I need help with the code for swapContacts() in javascript, please.  Here is what I am trying to use:

```
var i=0;    
for (i=0;i<document.form1.checkbox1.length;i++){
    $tempstr = document.form1.checkbox1[i].value;
    document.form1.checkbox1[i].value= document.form1.checkbox2[i].value;
    document.form1.checkbox2[i].value= $tempstr;
}
```

Comment: Can you please share the code you've tried and explain exactly what issue you ran into?

Comment: added javascript code, as you requested.  i know i'm a clown, just need you to post the javascript code i can use to swap the checked boxed from checkbox1 array and checkbox2 array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
function swapContacts() {
  let chks1 = document.querySelectorAll("input[name='checkbox1[]']");
  let chks2 = document.querySelectorAll("input[name='checkbox2[]']");

  let tmp
  for (let i = 0; i < chks1.length; i++) {
    // store val from 1
    tmp = chks1[i].checked;
    chks1[i].checked = chks2[i].checked;
    chks2[i].checked = tmp;

    //console.log(chks1[i], chks2[i]);
  }
}
```

```html
<a id='swap' href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="swapContacts();">Swap</a>
<br>
<input class='c_contactmethods' type='checkbox' name='checkbox1[]' value='1'>Phone<br>
<input class='c_contactmethods' type='checkbox' name='checkbox1[]' value='2'>Email<br>
<input class='c_contactmethods' type='checkbox' name='checkbox1[]' value='3'>Text<br>
<input class='c_contactmethods' type='checkbox' name='checkbox1[]' value='4'>Mail<br>
<br>
<input class='c_co_contactmethods' type='checkbox' name='checkbox2[]' value='1'>Phone<br>
<input class='c_co_contactmethods' type='checkbox' name='checkbox2[]' value='2'>Email<br>
<input class='c_co_contactmethods' type='checkbox' name='checkbox2[]' value='3'>Text<br>
<input class='c_co_contactmethods' type='checkbox' name='checkbox2[]' value='4'>Mail<br>
```

Comment: winner, winner, chicken dinner!  thank you so very much.  worked like a charm.  cheers!

Answer (score 0):

something like that ?

```js
const buttonSwap = document.getElementById('swap')
  ,   checkbox1n = document.querySelectorAll('input[name="checkbox1[]"]')
  ,   checkbox2n = document.querySelectorAll('input[name="checkbox2[]"]')
  ;
buttonSwap.onclick = () =>
  {
  let c1 = [...checkbox1n].map(cb=>cb.checked)
  let c2 = [...checkbox2n].map(cb=>cb.checked)
  checkbox1n.forEach((cb,i)=>cb.checked = c2[i])
  checkbox2n.forEach((cb,i)=>cb.checked = c1[i])
  }
```

```html
<button id="swap" type="button" >Swap</button>
<br>
 <label><input class='c_contactmethods' type='checkbox' name='checkbox1[]' value='1'>Phone</label><br>
 <label><input class='c_contactmethods' type='checkbox' name='checkbox1[]' value='2'>Email</label><br>
 <label><input class='c_contactmethods' type='checkbox' name='checkbox1[]' value='3'>Text</label><br>
 <label><input class='c_contactmethods' type='checkbox' name='checkbox1[]' value='4'>Mail</label><br>
 <br>
 <label><input class='c_co_contactmethods' type='checkbox' name='checkbox2[]' value='1'>Phone</label><br>
 <label><input class='c_co_contactmethods' type='checkbox' name='checkbox2[]' value='2'>Email</label><br>
 <label><input class='c_co_contactmethods' type='checkbox' name='checkbox2[]' value='3'>Text</label><br>
 <label><input class='c_co_contactmethods' type='checkbox' name='checkbox2[]' value='4'>Mail</label><br>
```

Comment: this requires that you click the <a>swap</a> twice and then the flip-flop is out of sync with some other fields on the form.  this is the closest I've gotten to making this work.  any suggestions to get it to swap on the first click?

Comment: @maybeahackbutitworks  I do not recommend using an href link for this kind of operation. and you didn't indicate that this was happening in a form, that's an important information, and I changed my code to make it work

Comment: @maybeahackbutitworks  you may also consider to add some `<label>` to your code to make any click on text to change your checkboxes checked in on/off (see on my code)

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate through the items, check whether the `set1` and `set2` have the item with the current index checked.

If it's unchecked, check the other. And vice versa.

```js
function swapContacts() {
  let set1 = document.querySelectorAll('input[name="checkbox1[]"]');
  let set2 = document.querySelectorAll('input[name="checkbox2[]"]');
  
  for(i=0; i<Math.min(set1.length, set2.length); i++) {
    const checkSet1 = set2[i].checked;
    const checkSet2 = set1[i].checked;
    
    set1[i].checked = checkSet1 ? "checked" : "";
    set2[i].checked = checkSet2 ? "checked" : "";
  }
  
  return false;
}
```

```html
<a id='swap' href="#" onclick="swapContacts(); return false;">Swap</a>
<br>
<input class='c_contactmethods' type='checkbox' name='checkbox1[]' value='1'>Phone<br>
<input class='c_contactmethods' type='checkbox' name='checkbox1[]' value='2'>Email<br>
<input class='c_contactmethods' type='checkbox' name='checkbox1[]' value='3'>Text<br>
<input class='c_contactmethods' type='checkbox' name='checkbox1[]' value='4'>Mail<br>
<br>
<input class='c_co_contactmethods' type='checkbox' name='checkbox2[]' value='1'>Phone<br>
<input class='c_co_contactmethods' type='checkbox' name='checkbox2[]' value='2'>Email<br>
<input class='c_co_contactmethods' type='checkbox' name='checkbox2[]' value='3'>Text<br>
<input class='c_co_contactmethods' type='checkbox' name='checkbox2[]' value='4'>Mail<br>
```